# What is the intuitive meaning of the weakest precondition expression $\text{wp}(S,R)$ in refinement calculus with miracles?

Tags: program-verification

What is the intuitive meaning of the expression $\text{wp}(S,R)$ ($\text{wp}$ = weakest precondition) in refinement calculus with miracles?

When the $\text{wp}$ function describes partial correctness (as in Hoare's calculus), $\text{wp}(S,R)$ means intuitively: if you start at a state satisfying $\text{wp}(S,R)$ and then proceed to execute the program $S$, then, if the computation terminates, the final state will satisfy $R$.

When the $\text{wp}$ function describes total correctness (as in Dijkstra's calculus), $\text{wp}(S,R)$ means intuitively: if you start at a state satisfying $\text{wp}(S,R)$ and then proceed to execute the program $S$, then the computation is guaranteed to terminate in a state satisfying $R$.

But what is the intuitive meaning of $\text{wp}(S,R)$ in refinement calculus with "miracles" (as in Carroll Morgan's textbook *Programming from Specifications*)? For instance, how should I understand the fact that $\text{wp}(S, \text{false}) = \text{true}$ when $S$ is the specification statement $x:[\text{true},\text{false}]$? Is it simply partial correctness? If so, then why introduce the concept of "miracles", and not just call it "partial correctness"?